# I am installing jenkins on Ubuntu 20.04 and it is failing to start

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins

Here is the output from ssystemctl status jenkins.service

```
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Wed 2021-02-17 16:04:06 UTC; 9min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 8933)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service

Feb 17 16:04:04 ip-172-31-50-225 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Feb 17 16:04:04 ip-172-31-50-225 jenkins[78774]: Correct java version found
Feb 17 16:04:04 ip-172-31-50-225 jenkins[78774]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Feb 17 16:04:04 ip-172-31-50-225 su[78826]: (to jenkins) root on none
Feb 17 16:04:04 ip-172-31-50-225 su[78826]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Feb 17 16:04:05 ip-172-31-50-225 su[78826]: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user jenkins
Feb 17 16:04:06 ip-172-31-50-225 jenkins[78774]:    ...done.
Feb 17 16:04:06 ip-172-31-50-225 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

Here is what i have in /etc/init.d/jenkins

```
# Which Java versions can be used to run Jenkins
JAVA_ALLOWED_VERSIONS=( "1.8" "11" ) 
# Work out the JAVA version we are working with:
#JAVA_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -n ';s/.* version "\([0-9]\{2,\}\|[0-9]\.[0-9]\)\..*".*/\1/p;')
#JAVA_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -n ';s/.* version "\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\..*".*/\1\2/p;')
JAVA_VERSION=$($JAVA -version 2>&1 | sed -n ';s/.* version "\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)\..*".*/\1\2/p;')
```

Below is what i get for java -version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_282"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~20.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
```

Any Suggestions?